# unpack statement in perl - template issue

Tags: perl, unpack

This is not my script. if it were, i would use strict and warnings. please excuse its vulgarity.
I just need to fix it.
This script turns this:

```
44049U44049U1042014101511:30:579999123100:00:00RL5  Horizons Seasonal Rotation ETF     HAC         B77D2K4All
44049W44049W1002014101511:32:549999123100:00:00RL5  Horizons Enhanced Income US Equity HEA         BJ3V9P0All
44049W44049W1002014101511:32:549999123100:00:00RL5  Horizons Enhanced Income US Equity HEA.U       B4L4291All
44050P44050P1012014101510:59:159999123100:00:00RL5  Horizons Active Canadian Dividend EHAL         B8GC630All
44050U44050U1002014101511:00:359999123100:00:00RL5  Horizons Auspice Managed Futures InHMF         B7M39S6All
44051W44051W1132014101511:02:049999123100:00:00RL5  Horizons Active Diversified Income HAA         B870J67All
44051X44051X1112014101511:04:169999123100:00:00RL5  Horizons Active Yield Matched DuratHAF         BDXGDG2All
```

Into this:

```
RL5, Horizons Seasonal Rotation ETF, HAC, All
RL5, Horizons Enhanced Income US Equity, HEA, All
RL5, Horizons Enhanced Income US Equity, HEA.U, All
RL5, Horizons Active Canadian Dividend E, HAL, All
RL5, Horizons Auspice Managed Futures In, HMF, All
RL5, Horizons Active Diversified Income, HAA, All
RL5, Horizons Active Yield Matched Durat, HAF, All
```

The problem is with the EHAL. The script below turns the EHAL into E, HAL. And I think that is has somethine to do
with the unpack statement.  I really do not undestand the upackstatement -  I thought it needs a corresponding 'pack'
statement and there is not one in the script.

```
my ($restrict, $company, $symbol, $sectype) = unpack "x47A5A35A12x7A4", $_;
```

Funny thing is is that I do not see a pack statement in the script - the unpack works, just not in this case for the
EHAL - it gets split into E,HAL which screws up alot of downstream processes.

```
casper@70pap:/scripts/WebDownloads$ cat FOORestrictedList.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
$today_date = `date +%d-%b-%Y`;
chop($today_date);
use LWP::Simple;  # for internet proxy stuff^M
use LWP::UserAgent;  # for internet proxy stuff^M
use LWP::Debug qw(+ -trace);
$url="http://casper.com/rlist/download/RESTRLISTCLASS.DAT";

$save = "restricted.csv";

%FOOsymbol = ();

    $getContent= getstore($url,$save);

$i = 1;

my %restricted = map { $_ => undef } qw(RL3 RL5 RL5H RL6 REGM RAF RLMT RTCA RTCAH RTCB RTCBH RTCI RTCIH RLSI RLHK RLJP RPROP RLCB RLCS RLBZ RLBZH RLSUS);

$file=$save;
$outfile="restricted.html";
open( FILE, "< $file " ) or die "Can't open $file : $!";



while ( <FILE> ) {
    chomp;
    my ($restrict, $company, $symbol, $sectype) = unpack "x47A5A35A12x7A4", $_;
    if ($FOOsymbol{$symbol} && ($sectype ne "Debt") && ($sectype ne "SpecificSecurity")
        && exists $restricted{$restrict})
    {
        print "Restricted FOO: $restrict $company $symbol\n";
        print $restrict $company $symbol";
        push(@restricted_sym_list,$symbol);
    }
    elsif ($FOOsymbol{$symbol}) {
        print "FOO, but OK: $restrict $company $symbol $sectype\n";
    }
    elsif (exists $restricted{$restrict} && ($POSITION{$symbol})) {
        print  qq|$restrict$company$symbol (position only, not in FOO)|;
        $t = 10;
    }
}
```

~

Comment: It looks like a data issue to me - the data doesn't fit in the field.  The unpack has a "A35" which appears to be intended to capture the field that starts with "Horizons…"  But on the problem line the "E" of EHAL falls into the 35th character of that field.  You'll notice that other lines appear to have truncated fields: e.g. "DuratHAF" splits to "Durat, HAF".  This line is similar, I'd guess that the E is the first letter of a word like "ETF".

Comment: EHAL is a symbols on a Canadian options exchange, which we do not trade in - HAL is the Halliburton Company, which we do trade in. the unpack is turning EHAL into HAL and telling alot of downstream engine not to trade it - which is a real pain in the neck because I have to manually enable it on each of the engines.

Comment: as martin says, the E of the EHAL is "in the wrong column".  You either need to move the EHAL data into the correct column or totally alter the way that the file is processed

Comment: so unpack is like a bash cut command?

Comment: you guys are correct - it is the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the software is correct. It seems to me as if there is a 35-character field with the name of the entity in it, followed by an abbreviation, with **no space** between them. If the entity name is longer than 35 characters, it is truncated to that length. (Think `printf` with a format of `"%-35.35s"`.)

I think your entity here is "[Horizons Active Canadian Dividend ETF](http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/HAL:CN)" which is abbreviated to HAL on the Canadian markets. The "TF" is lost because characters after 35 are truncated, and "EHAL" is a red herring.

If you're having problems in follow-on processes, it might be for another reason, such as that it is confusing a Canadian market abbreviation with an American one.